# How to check what triggered a Jenkins Job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to make a job parametrized but i would like to check the previous step that triggered the current job. How to check that?

Answer (score 4):

From a Pipeline script, you can do something like this:

```groovy
@NonCPS
def getAllCauses() {
  currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses().toString()
}

stage('print causes') {
  echo getAllCauses()
}
```

This will print out something like this:

```groovy
[hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause@a05b0080]
```

If you want more detailed info, you're going to have to massage it out of the `hudson.model.Cause` instances.  For instance, here's a snippet that returns a list of users "responsible" for a build, where a user is considered "responsible" if they contributed a commit to the build or if they caused the build (i.e. by logging in to the web UI and clicking the "Build Now" button):

```groovy
@NonCPS
def getResponsibleUsers() {
  def build = currentBuild.rawBuild
  def users = build.getCauses().collect() { cause->
    def causeType = cause.getClass()
    if (causeType == jenkins.branch.BranchIndexingCause) {
      return build.changeSets.collect() { set->
        set.collect { entry->
          entry.getAuthor()
        }
      }
    } else if (causeType == hudson.model.Cause$UserIdCause) {
      return User.get(cause.getUserName())
    } else { 
      return []
    }      
  }

  return users.flatten().unique()
}

stage('print responsible users') {
  echo getResponsibleUsers()
}
```

Comment: This requires some whitelisting in sandboxed pipeslines, but I think this is the most complete answer. [JENKINS-41272](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41272) is open for better built-in support.

Comment: I believe it does require some whitelisting.  If you put the `getResponsibleUsers()` function into a shared library, the whitelisting shouldn't be necessary (in theory, anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Similar to jayhendren's answer but a bit simpler we use do:

```
/**
* Retrieves list of causes that generated job execution
*
* @return list
*/
List getCauses() {

    return currentBuild.rawBuild.getCauses().collect { it.getClass().getCanonicalName().tokenize('.').last() }

}
```

This returns: `['TimerTriggerCause']` If it was a cron scheduler trigger for example.

From there you just need to know what causes your looking or not looking for and search the list.